Some Video Files Not loading in Flutter using Flick And Video player
I am getting error in playing videos i try to play videos from network some of the video files works fine but some giviging me this error
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [] onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient( 5575): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): connecting to surface 0x7db9d58010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec( 5575): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] setting surface generation to 5708807
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): disconnecting from surface 0x7db9d58010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): connecting to surface 0x7db9d58010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/MediaCodec( 5575): failed to configure codec bacause of codec capacity
E/MediaCodec( 5575): Codec reported err 0xffffec77, actionCode 0, while in state 3
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): disconnecting from surface 0x7db9d58010, reason disconnectFromSurface
E/MediaCodec( 5575): configure failed with err 0xffffec77, resetting...
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8312
I/MediaCodec( 5575): Codec shutdown complete
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [] onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient( 5575): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575): Preferred decoder instantiation failed. Sleeping for 50ms then retrying.
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8312
I/MediaCodec( 5575): Codec shutdown complete
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
I/BpBinder( 5575): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: android.media.IResourceManagerService
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [] onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient( 5575): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): connecting to surface 0x7e14629010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec( 5575): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] setting surface generation to 5708808
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): disconnecting from surface 0x7e14629010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): connecting to surface 0x7e14629010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/MediaCodec( 5575): failed to configure codec bacause of codec capacity
E/MediaCodec( 5575): Codec reported err 0xffffec77, actionCode 0, while in state 3
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
D/SurfaceUtils( 5575): disconnecting from surface 0x7e14629010, reason disconnectFromSurface
E/MediaCodec( 5575): configure failed with err 0xffffec77, resetting...
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8312
I/MediaCodec( 5575): Codec shutdown complete
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [] onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient( 5575): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  ( 5575): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  ( 5575):  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8312
I/MediaCodec( 5575): Codec shutdown complete
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
D/MediaCodec( 5575): flushMediametrics
I/BpBinder( 5575): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: android.media.IResourceManagerService
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575): Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):   android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2127)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2043)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:51)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:113)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
W/MediaCodecRenderer( 5575):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575): Video codec error
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640034, -1, null, [4096, 2160, 30.0], [-1, -1])
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1021)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):   Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2127)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2043)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:51)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:113)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 5575):       ... 10 more
D/MediaCodecInfo( 5575): NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.640034, video/avc] [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, video/avc] [a20, SM-A205F, samsung, 30]
D/MediaCodecInfo( 5575): NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 4096x2160@30.0] [c2.android.avc.decoder, video/avc] [a20, SM-A205F, samsung, 30]
D/MediaCodecInfo( 5575): NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.640034, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [a20, SM-A205F, samsung, 30]
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5575): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5575):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640034, -1, null, [4096, 2160, 30.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITIES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5575):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:578)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5575):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5575):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5575):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5575):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640034, -1, null, [4096, 2160, 30.0], [-1, -1])

Here is my Code could you please let me know where i am going wrong
import 'package:flick_video_player/flick_video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:innerlight/AppConstant/ThemeColors.dart';
import 'package:innerlight/AppUtils/AppUtils.dart';
import 'package:innerlight/Controllers/GeneralController.dart';
import 'package:innerlight/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  String videoUrl;

  VideoPlayer({super.key, required this.videoUrl});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayer> createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}

class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayer> {
  late FlickManager flickManager;

  var themeColors = ThemeColors();
  var utils = AppUtils();

  var generalRead = navigatorkey.currentContext!.read<GeneralController>();
  var generalWatch = navigatorkey.currentContext!.watch<GeneralController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    flickManager = FlickManager(
        videoPlayerController:
            VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(widget.videoUrl)));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();

    flickManager.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: themeColors.backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: themeColors.backgroundColor,
        title: Text(
          "Video Player",
          style: utils.headingStyleB(themeColors.whiteColor),
        ),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: themeColors.whiteColor),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 12 / 10,
          child: FlickVideoPlayer(
            flickManager: flickManager,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

i only plays mp4 videos some url works fine but some url's give me error i couldn't understand why this happeing

The videos that give errors, have you tried them on the browser and they work as expected?

Yes i play them on the browser they are working fine there but when i try to play them in the app it is getting intiailize and not play
